# I have a problem with the discord bot that gives an automatic roll to every new user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a discord bot that will give an automatic roll to any new user who enters the site and it does not work (I am actually interested in this way that the code should work according to the roll ID because my rollers' names are in a foreign language) I would be happy if someone could help me understand
The code is attached.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member)  => { 
  let welcomeRole = member.guild.roles.cache.get("814461419298750475");
  if (!welcomeRole) return console.log('Couldn\'t find the member role.');
  member.roles.add(welcomeRole);
})
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is the role simply not being applied?

Comment: This is what happens when an action is run (when a new user logs on to the server)
See attached link
https://prnt.sc/10dbibn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message that you show in : https://prnt.sc/10dbibn

It clearly stated that your bot *doesn't have the permission to do that.*

Try giving your bot the "**Manage Role**" permission and retry to see if that fixes your issue !